# How do you connect peer2peer in java?

Tags: java, tcp, p2p

So on this project I need to transfer the file from one client to another in java. This has a menu, where if you type DOWNLOAD and some other things the process will start. But it seems I'm stuck on the other client waiting for a command from the console, and even when I do type it it only stays on the while=true part. This is the code in question for the client.

```
package napster;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TPCCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String serverHost = "localhost"; // Endereço do servidor RMI -> "127.0.0.1"
            int serverPort = 1099; // Porta do servidor RMI

            // Obtém uma referência para o registro RMI no servidor
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverHost, serverPort);

            // Obtém a referência para o objeto remoto do servidor
            napster.JoinService clientJOIN = (napster.JoinService) registry.lookup("JoinService");
            napster.SearchService clientSEARCH = (napster.SearchService) registry.lookup("SearchService");
            napster.UpdateService clientUPDATE = (napster.UpdateService) registry.lookup("UpdateService");

            // Dados do cliente
            InetAddress enderecoIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();  // IP
            String peerIP = enderecoIP.getHostAddress();

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);   // PORTA
            int peerPort = serverSocket.getLocalPort();

            // lista dos arquivos da pasta, lógica abaixo
            List<String> nomesArquivos = listarArquivosNaPasta("C:\\Users\\Helena\\Documents\\projeto napster\\cliente1");
            String pasta = "C:\\Users\\Helena\\Documents\\projeto napster\\cliente1";

            String nomesArquivosEM_STRING = String.join(" ", nomesArquivos);  // faz a lista virar uma única string

            // Chama o método JOIN no servidor (menu interativo)
            System.out.println("Digite JOIN para se conectar ao servidor.");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  // cria instância para ler o teclado
            String chaveJOIN = reader.readLine();
            while (!chaveJOIN.equals("JOIN")) {      // loop até que o join seja requisitado para o servidor
                System.out.println("Digite JOIN para se conectar ao servidor.");
                chaveJOIN = reader.readLine();
            }
            String juntar = clientJOIN.join(peerIP, peerPort, nomesArquivos);

            // Processa a resposta do servidor
            System.out.println("Resposta do servidor: " + juntar);
            System.out.println("Sou peer " + peerIP + ":" + peerPort + " com arquivos " + nomesArquivosEM_STRING);

            while (true) {
                // todo lógica para os requests
                System.out.println("Digite SEARCH para pesquisar arquivo, DOWNLOAD para baixar arquivo e UPDATE para atualizar o servidor");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientseederSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// Verificar qual fonte de entrada está disponível primeiro
                if (input.ready()) {
                    // Ler do fluxo de entrada do socket
                    String mensagem = input.readLine();
                    // Processar a mensagem recebida do socket
                    // ...
                } else if (consoleInput.ready()) {
                    // Ler do console
                    String entradaConsole = consoleInput.readLine();
                    // Processar a entrada do console
                    // ...
                }
                String pedidoProServer = reader.readLine();
                if (pedidoProServer.equals("SEARCH")) {
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo que deseja procurar.");
                    String pesquisa = reader.readLine();
                    String pesquisar = clientSEARCH.search(pesquisa);
                    System.out.println(pesquisar);
                } else if (pedidoProServer.equals("DOWNLOAD")) {

                    System.out.println("Digite o clientkey de quem quiser baixar");
                    String chaveCliente = reader.readLine();
                    String[] partes = chaveCliente.split(":");  // divide a chave em suas partes
                    String ClienteSeederIP = partes[0];
                    int ClienteSeederPorta = Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);

                    Socket seederSocket = new Socket(ClienteSeederIP, ClienteSeederPorta);
                    DataOutputStream seederOutput = new DataOutputStream(seederSocket.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(seederSocket.getInputStream()));

                    // Enviar mensagem de solicitação para o cliente seeder
                    seederOutput.writeBytes("DOWNLOAD_REQUEST\n");

                    // Enviar o nome do arquivo que deseja baixar para o cliente seeder
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo que deseja baixar:");
                    String nomeArquivoDownload = reader.readLine();
                    seederOutput.writeBytes(nomeArquivoDownload + "\n");

                    // Recebe resposta do cliente seeder
                    BufferedReader seederResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(seederSocket.getInputStream()));
                    String response = seederResponse.readLine();
                    System.out.println(response);

                    if (response.equals("DOWNLOAD_ACCEPTED")) {
                        // Recebe o arquivo do cliente que possui o arquivo
                        InputStream fileStream = seederSocket.getInputStream();
                        String fileName = seederResponse.readLine();
                        long fileSize = Long.parseLong(seederResponse.readLine());

                        // Envia mensagem de confirmação para o ClienteSeeder
                        Socket clientSeederSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                        // Envia a mensagem de confirmação para o ClienteSeeder
                        DataOutputStream clientSeederOutput = new DataOutputStream(clientSeederSocket.getOutputStream());
                        clientSeederOutput.writeBytes("CONFIRMATION_REQUEST\n");

                        // Recebe a resposta do ClienteSeeder
                        BufferedReader clientSeederResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSeederSocket.getInputStream()));
                        String clientSeederReply = clientSeederResponse.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Resposta do ClienteSeeder: " + clientSeederReply);

                        // Se o ClienteSeeder aceitar a transferência, inicie o processo de download
                        if (clientSeederReply.equals("ACCEPT")) {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(pasta + "\\" + fileName);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int bytesRead;
                            long totalBytesRead = 0;

                            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                                if (totalBytesRead == fileSize) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            fileOutput.close();
                            System.out.println("Download concluído!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Transferência rejeitada pelo ClienteSeeder.");
                        }

                        // Fecha o socket do ClienteSeeder
                        clientSeederSocket.close();
                    }
                } else if (pedidoProServer.equals("UPDATE")) {
                    // atualiza lista de arquivos no servidor
                    clientUPDATE.update(peerIP, peerPort, nomesArquivos);
                    System.out.println("Arquivos atualizados no servidor!");
                } else if (pedidoProServer.equals("DOWNLOAD_REQUEST")) {
                    // Receber o nome do arquivo solicitado do cliente requisitante
                    String nomeArquivoDownload = reader.readLine();

                    // Verificar se o arquivo existe no diretório do cliente seeder
                    String caminhoArquivo = pasta + "\\" + nomeArquivoDownload;
                    File arquivo = new File(caminhoArquivo);

                    if (arquivo.exists()) {
                        // Enviar resposta de aceitação para o cliente requisitante
                        DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.accept().getOutputStream());
                        clientOutput.writeBytes("DOWNLOAD_ACCEPT\n");

                        // Enviar o nome do arquivo e o tamanho para o cliente requisitante
                        clientOutput.writeBytes(nomeArquivoDownload + "\n");
                    } else {
                        // Enviar resposta de arquivo não encontrado para o cliente requisitante
                        DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.accept().getOutputStream());
                        clientOutput.writeBytes("FILE_NOT_FOUND\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> listarArquivosNaPasta(String pasta) throws IOException {
        List<String> nomesArquivos = new ArrayList<>();
        Files.list(Paths.get(pasta)).forEach(path -> nomesArquivos.add(path.getFileName().toString()));
        return nomesArquivos;
    }
}
```

Thank you!